# How to pass result from one function into another function

Tags: ipython

Hello consider following part of code:

```
'def sum(ab,bc):
    cd = ab + bc
    return cd

ab = 5
bc = 6

sum(ab,bc)
print(cd)'
```

When I run this part of code I have as outcome:

NameError: name 'cd' is not defined

But cd is the outcome of the Sum function no? So why is it not defined.

Secondly how can I pas the result of the sum function to another function.
Eg let's say I have also a diff function:

```
def diff (x,y):
    ef = x - y
    return ef

diff(cd,3)'
```

When I run this part of code I have also as result cd is not defined.
But cd is the result of my previous sum function no?

Answer (score 1):

`cd`, in your case, is a variable whose scope is the function `sum()` so it will be allocated on the call of the function then deallocated when the function returns. To print the result you have to do something like this:

```
def sum(ab,bc):
    cd = ab + bc
    return cd

ab = 5
bc = 6

res=sum(ab,bc)
print(res)'
```

if you want to 'debug', you have to do the print 'inside' the function body

```
def sum(ab,bc):
    cd = ab + bc
    print cd
    return cd
```

also i'll avoid to use `cd` and other 'reserved' words as variable names as results may get corrupted.